# What is this black speaker-like module inside my laptop?

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I opened up my [Oryx Pro](https://system76.com/laptops/oryx) laptop and noticed this interesting speaker-y box pointing towards the bottom of the computer.

It is mounted with two diagonal normal screws, and two spring / flex pins. It is wired with the black/white wire coming from the bottom right, connecting to the board in the middle left.

[image]

It has this position with relation to the rest of the board:

[image]

A side view:

[image]

On the other side of the bottom panel is this cover for it:

[image]

I know it isn't

- a speaker or microphone because the speakers are near the keyboard on the top, and the builtin microphone is beside the webcam,
- a subwoofer because it does not make any sound, even when playing loud bass-heavy music, or
- another sound or input device as detected by Linux or Windows, and tools like `lshw`, `lsusb` or Device Manager don't seem to list it.

It isn't listed on the Oryx's product page or spec, and it's unlike anything I've ever seen inside a modern computer.

Before I dare disassemble and inspect it, can anyone identify this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [User Manual](https://www.scribd.com/document/341596841/Clevo-650hp-Sager-Np8155-System76-Oryp3-Oryx-Pro), it is a sub-woofer.

[image: Bottom View of Oryx Pro:]

Comment: Well, it doesn't make any sound or produce bass and the sound seems to lack bass, so maybe it is not configured right